# How to use react-table for a local json file?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, pagination, react-table

I have a rather simple question on using react-table from React.js.

I cannot find any samples nor documents regarding useMemo for a local json, pretty much all of the tutorials are based on asyn api.

The objective is to create a table as such:
https://codesandbox.io/s/github/tannerlinsley/react-table/tree/master/examples/pagination?file=/src/App.js

The only difference between the tutorial and mine, is the makeData file would be an actual json file with legit data.

This is what I tried:

```
  const data = React.useMemo(() => Sales, [])
```

which obviously did not work, and sent back TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like useMemo expects the data to be formatted as an array containing objects, versus the raw json format you're currently providing.

**Importing the JSON**

Depending on modules available, either use the built in json loader, or wrap your json file inside a ts/js file e.g.

```
const Data = { "thing": "value }
export default Data
```

and import via

```
import jsonData from './data.json'
```

**Processing the JSON**

There may be a more elegant way to do this,
In this case, I was able to get something working by creating a helper function to preprocess the data.  It just takes advantage uses keys/map to iterate over the JSON and stuff each value into an array.

```
function processData(jsonData) {
  const result = Object.keys(jsonData).map((key) => { 
    return jsonData[key];
  });
  return result;
}
```

so, from the example you provided instead of

```
const data = React.useMemo(() => makeData(100000), []);
```

the line is

```
const data = React.useMemo(() => processData(jsonData), []);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

is caused by not adding the "rows" property beneath the function Table,
add rows, and pages. Add rows under page, along with:

```
const data = React.useMemo(() => processData(jsonData), []);
```

and:

```
function processData(jsonData) {
  const result = Object.keys(jsonData).map((key) => {return jsonData[key]; });
  return result;
}
```